# print 3 or more consecutive symbols of a kind present in an array in php

Tags: php

I have a problem printing 3 or 4 or 5 consecutive symbols of the same kind present in row in an array after using the array_rand function

This is the code

//using the array_rand function to generate any 15 random symbols :

```
     $roles15 = 15;
     $newOne = array();
     $arrayOfSymbols = array(N, A, B, D, F, Q,L, BA, CA).
           for ($b = 0; $b < $roles15 ;$b++) { 
               $newOne[] = $no[array_rand($no)];

              //so for instance if there are 3 or more consecutive symbols of the same kind in a row.for instance the array may look like [N, N, N, Q, B, B, N, Q, BA, BA, BA, BA, F, L, A] print the print the  3 , 4 and 5 consecutive symbols of the same kind
        }
```

if there are are 3 or 4 or 5 consecutive symbols of the same kind present in the an array in a row for instance [N, N, N, Q, B, B, N, Q, BA, BA, BA, BA, F, L, A] after using the array_rand function
print the  3 or 4 or 5 consecutive symbols of the same kind

Comment: So what exactly is your expected result for the given example? What have you tried so far in terms of checking for “consecutive” symbols?

Comment: I have tried several efforts but I just cant figure it out.

Comment: what's your expected output

Comment: _Show us_ your efforts - otherwise they are just _pretend_ efforts. And, again, give a proper example of what exact output you actually expect with the given input data.

Comment: array('N', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', "D', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'Q', 'L', 'P', 'Z') I want the expected result to be print 3 A and 4 D

Answer (score 1):

This solution works on remembering the previous character and incrementing a running count each time it's encountered.  Then when a new character is encountered, check how often the last run was and display if it's > 2.  Then reset the counter and previous counter variable...

```
$prev = '';
$prevCount = 1;
foreach ( $arrayOfSymbols as $symbol )  {
    if ( $prev == $symbol )  {
        $prevCount++;
    }
    else    {
        if ( $prevCount > 2 )    {
            echo "{$prev} occured {$prevCount}".PHP_EOL;
        }
        $prev = $symbol;
        $prevCount = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the actual solution Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$row  = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b' , 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'];
$runs = [];
$n    = 0;
$last = null;
foreach($row as $symbol) {
    if($symbol !== $last)
        $n++;
    $runs[$n][] = $symbol;
    $last = $symbol;
}

foreach($runs as $run) {
    $run_count = count($run);
    if($run_count>2) {
        echo $run_count , $run[0], ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3b 4c 3a
```

The contents of `$runs`:

```
 var_export($runs);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'a',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      0 => 'b',
      1 => 'b',
      2 => 'b',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      0 => 'c',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      0 => 'a',
      1 => 'a',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      0 => 'c',
      1 => 'c',
      2 => 'c',
      3 => 'c',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      0 => 'a',
      1 => 'a',
      2 => 'a',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This also is the solution Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$arrayOfSymbols = array('N', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'Q', 'Q', 'L', 'P', 'Z');

$numberOfTimes = array_count_values($arrayOfSymbols);

foreach ($numberOfTimes as $key=>$number)
{
    if ($number > 1)
    {
        print ($key . ' exists ' . $number . ' times in the array. ');

    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

> A exists 3 times in the array. Q exists 2 times in the array.

Comment: Thanks Leif_Lundberg for helping out.  what if the array is like this array('N', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', "D', 'D', 'D', 'F', 'Q', 'L', 'P', 'Z') I want the result to be print 3 A and 4 D

Comment: The OP is looking for _consecutive_ symbols of the same kind...

Comment: The result printed will be 3 A and 4 D, but lovelace is correct, that will be printed regardless of where A and D are to be found in the array and not of they are consecutive. Give me a moment.

Comment: Nigel Ren and Progrock got the solution thanks for helping out